# Summing up numbers from multiple columns (by Sumproduct?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to sum up numbers from different columns which have the same titles, but not all of them have all the dates.
The Pivot tables involved are very complicated so I can't just merge them.
Is there any formula to help me with this? I assume sumproduct could help.

In the [attached sample Excel file](http://ge.tt/1easoWt2), if row 28 (16/12/2018), for example, is done manually, it will look like:

```
Cell B28: =SUM(B6, F5)
Cell C28: =SUM(G5, K4)
Cell D28: =SUM(C6, H5, L4)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1385964/edit) to let us know what you have tried, and where the problem is?

Comment: SUMIF() may be the formula you're looking for. How many pivot tables do you have? If, for example, you just want to total all of the cells for a given date in "Sum of Gross Revenue" columns, SUMIF can do this, although the more ranges/tables you have, the longer and messier the formula will become

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to make it manual. If they all had the same dates, I would have done one SUMIF to sum by column titles (which repeat themselves), for example `=sumif(1:1, "Sum of Fee", 4:4)`

Comment: If you use this formula in B24 and drag down the column, it will sum your gross revenues from Source 1 and Source 2. You can add additional similar SUMIF terms within the SUM to include other Source tables as well. This equation does not scale well, that's why I asked how many pivot tables you have. =SUM(SUMIF($A$4:$A$21,$A24,$B$4:$B$21),SUMIF($E$4:$E$21,$A24,$F$4:$F$21))

Comment: The number of pivot tables is dynamic and they don't always have all the columns (as shown in the screenshot)...

Comment: @LWC, you have Date  in 3 Columns `A, E & J` but no value along side to SUM,,, and one more would you like to use Date as Criteria from all 3 Columns to SUM corresponding values?

Comment: I just blanked out the numbers if the different "Sum of" columns, but what you have there is just plain numbers. Actually, I've just attached a sample file so you can just download and see. Yes, date is the criteria. I make a summary of dates so next to each of them I want the total sum from all columns above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had specified a specific range for all the sum & date.. you may use the index()+ match() strategy and combine it to become "value1 + value2 + value3"

Initiate this formula in B26.

value1 is.. the sum value from source1 of the data defined in A26, if not found(error), then returns 0. Or ..

`IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$21,MATCH($A26,$A$4:$A$21,0)),0)`

then value 2 is from source2, or :

`IFERROR(INDEX($F$4:$F$20,MATCH($A26,$E$4:$E$20,0)),0)`

and so does for value3 :

`IFERROR(INDEX($K$4:$K$19,MATCH($A26,$J$4:$J$19,0)),0)`

combining it.. total = value1+value2+value3

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$21,MATCH($A26,$A$4:$A$21,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($F$4:$F$20,MATCH($A26,$E$4:$E$20,0)),0)+
IFERROR(INDEX($K$4:$K$19,MATCH($A26,$J$4:$J$19,0)),0)`

this one should be in cell B6.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the advantage over sumif? It still doesn't support any number of pivot tables with dynamic columns (as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: "advantage over sumif? " I'd rather say.. its an alternative.. sum with sumif will work too If you look at how the formula works.. both actually compares the source date 1st.. then load the revenue value to be sum up later (same as value1 + value2 + value3). || Technically, sumif can 'collects' the revenue if there is more than one match in each source.. ie.. 2 same dates, different row/value. Since this is not your case, it works the same. || The only way I see that to accommodate the dynamic row requirement.. ( which you should mention in the main question.. not comment) is to move the  ..

Comment: .. A24:D23 table to say, R2:U21. a place where it is not in the same column as source1,2,3,.. then update this index-match formula to : `=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($R4,$A:$A,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F,MATCH($R4,$E:$E,0)),0)+
IFERROR(INDEX($K:$K,MATCH($R4,$J:$J,0)),0)` || or you may put it in the A-D column and source1 in F-H column source2 in J-M column( an so on..), and shift the source1,2,3 columns ref accordingly.